# Microsoft C++ exception runtime_error at memory location (Code 0x75A818A2)

Tags: c++, exception

I have the following class definition:

```
class DisplayManager
{
public:
    static DisplayManager *getInstance();
    DisplayManager(DisplayManager const&) = delete;
    void operator=(DisplayManager const&) = delete;
    ~DisplayManager();

    void addDisplay(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY &display);
private:
    DisplayManager();

    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *mDisplay = nullptr;
};
```

The implementation of the class is:

```
DisplayManager *DisplayManager::getInstance()
{
    static DisplayManager instance;
    return &instance;
}

DisplayManager::~DisplayManager()
{}

void DisplayManager::addDisplay(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY &display)
{
    if(!mDisplay)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create display: A display is already created.");
    }

    mDisplay = &display;
}

DisplayManager::DisplayManager()
{
}
```

The `addDisplay()` method is called by another class like:

```
void Display::createDisplay()
{
    auto *manager = DisplayManager::getInstance();

    if(!manager)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("No diplay manager.");
    }

    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = al_create_display(width, height);

    if(!display)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create display");
    }

    manager->addDisplay(*display);
}
```

In `addDisplay()` method, when I do `mDisplay = &display;`, I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x75A818A2 in My_Executable.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x0073F66C.
```

The application is working as expected despite this exception. I can't quite figure out the reason for this exception.

EDIT 1:

I tried to put a try-catch:

```
try
{
    mDisplay = &display;
}
catch(const std::exception&)
{
// Couldn't reach this code.
}
```

When I tried this, strangest thing happened. I get the exact same exception and it is raised at the line that contains `try`...

EDIT 2:

Link to documentation on [al_create_display()](https://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/display.html#al_create_display). It returns a raw pointer to a display.

EDIT 3:

I suspected that it's the assignment operator that is causing the issue. So I tried replacing my `ALLEGRO_BITMAP *mDisplay` with a `std::vector<ALLEGRO_BITMAP *>` and instead of doing `mDisplay = &display`, I did `mDisplay.push_back(&display)`. Now, the exception disappeared. I really appreciate it if anyone can shed more light into it. May be the copy assignment operator is disabled?

Comment: If what you have and what you store is a pointer to a `ALLEGRO_DISPLAY`, why do you pass it by reference to the `addDisplay` function? Why not simply pass the pointer as-is?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just preference. I try to make my own methods accept reference rather than pointers, to avoid null checks, etc. Anyway, I did try with the pointer, but the error happens when I do a `if(!display)`.

Comment: As for your exception, you throw multiple exceptions in the code shown (and maybe s few in the code you don't show). Which one is the source of your problem? Doesn't the exception output show  the text? Perhaps you should catch the exception to know which one it is? Or perhaps even create your own exception classes (yes, plural) to throw, and you'll know better where the exception originated.

Comment: Since some of the structures are pointers originally, you *still* need null-pointer checks, just not maybe in your class.

Comment: And talking about null-pointer checks, you have one in `addDisplay` for the `mDisplay` member. I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) for that check.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added a try catch and edited the question. The exception has no other details... and I can't find any documentation for Microsoft Exception `0x75A818A2`.

Comment: @swdon -- `ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = al_create_display(width, height);` -- What is `al_create_display(width, height);`?  Why the assumption that what is returned is valid?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Added an edit. It's from Allegro5 which basically creates a window and returns a raw pointer to it. I need to call `al_destroy_display()` to destroy it.

Comment: When you catch the exception you need to print the result of the exceptions `what` function. And again, you *really* need to check that condition in the `addDisplay` function.

Answer (score 1):

hope this can help you see the comment below:

```
void DisplayManager::addDisplay(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY &display)
{
    if(!mDisplay)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create display: A display is already created.");
    }

    mDisplay = &display; // dangerous to do this, mDisplay point to display
//if display is being destroy => mDisplay point to un-legal memory
}
```

look at where we call it

```
ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = al_create_display(width, height); // problem in here
 //if this function return object which will being destroyed later, then error happen

if(!display)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create display");
}

manager->addDisplay(*display); // look at this, when we are out of this 
//and the object above is being destroy, mDisplay point to un-legal memory => exception
```

Comment: Destructors are not called on pointers when they go out of scope.  And the Library that creates the pointer, expects the client code to call `al_destroy_display(...)`

Comment: where did you call it? if you call destroy before destroy object `instance`, you will have error. and this object is static then it will exist in long time until program exit. could you test that you don't call `al_destroy_display(...)` in anywhere. @JonathonK

Comment: @theboy I call `al_destroy_display()` in `DisplayManager` singleton class, at the end of program execution. What I'm trying to accomplish is to pass the ownership of display to `DisplayManager`. No one else is calling `al_destroy_display()`.

Comment: @swdon please try to don't call it first to know the root cause. if you don't call and the exception not happen, then it is the root cause.